# SQL - Second highest

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve below leet code problem.

https://leetcode.com/problems/second-highest-salary

What is wrong with this answer? Below answer is not accepted :(

```
select t.salary as SecondHighestSalary from
(
    select salary
    from employee
    order by salary desc
    limit 1 offset 1
) as t
```

Comment: What's wrong with: `SELECT DISTINCT salary secondhighestsalary FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1;` ?

Comment: Two employees could have the same salary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - thats a good point.

Answer (score 0):

This is Accepted.

```
select salary as SecondHighestSalary
from employee a
where 1 = (select count(1) from employee b where b.salary < a.salary )
```

Your query will not work if the lowest salary appears twice in the table.

Above query uses co-related subquery, means, for each row in outer table the subquery (or inner query) will be executed once.

Moreover, this will work for Nth highest salary. If 10th highest salary would have been asked then just replace the 1 in the above query with 9.

Comment: Incidentally, it's a correlated subquery, and I can't help feeling this is over complicating the problem

Answer (score 0):

Both the below answers are accepted

We can use subquery as shown below:

```
SELECT MAX(salary) AS secondhighestsalary
  FROM employee
 WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary)
                 FROM employee);
```

or alternatively you can use temporary table:

```
with temp as
(
SELECT MAX(salary) as salary FROM employee
)
select max(salary) as secondhighestsalary from employee where salary <(select salary from temp);
```